# I want to test non woven fabrics to see if they are polypropylene, the lining material of N95 masks

Tags: biomedical-engineering, product-engineering, waterproofing

A group of us are sewing face masks to prevent the spread of sputum. I've learned that the lining of an N95 mask is made of polypropylene.  Polypropylene is also a common interfacing product for sewing.  I want to identify polypropylene in non woven breathable "fabric" products that I have on hand around the house, for example: some "plastic" grocery bags are breathable and, I suspect, made of polypropylene.

Is there a simple test?  The burn test?

Comment: For starters, polypro floats. It has a density of about 0.9 for common meltblown fiber.